# C# jagged array type declaration in reverse

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I just had one of these "What the..." moments. Is the following intended and is there some obscure reasoning behind the "non-natural" declaration of arrays in C#?

```
int[,][] i; // declares an 2D - array where each element is an int[] !
// you have to use it like this:
i = new int[2,3][];
i[1,2] = new int[0];
```

I would have expected the other way around. int[,][] declares an 1-dimensional array where each element is a two dimensional array.

Funny though, the type's Name is reversed:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int[,][]).Name); // prints "Int32[][,]"
```

Can someone explain this? Is this intentionally? (Using .NET 4.5 under Windows.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find a lengthy discussion in Eric Lippert's  blog [Arrays of arrays](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx).

> What C# actually does
>
> It’s a mess. No matter which option we choose, something ends up not
>   matching our intuition. Here’s what we actually chose in C#.
>
> First off: option two [It’s a two-dimensional array, each element is a one-dimensional array of ints] is correct. We force you to live with the
>   weirdness entailed by Consequence One; you do not actually make an
>   element type into an array of that type by appending an array
>   specifier. You make it into an array type by prepending the specifier
>   to the list of existing array specifiers. Crazy but true.

The word 'prepending' partly explains your output of the reversed type-name. A CLR type name is not necessarily the same as the C# declaration.

But the more relevant quote is at the bottom:

> That all said, **multidimensional ragged arrays are almost certainly a bad code smell.**

Comment: Thank you for the link. It explains everything. I totally disagree with his reasoning what is "sensible", but that's another topic. At least now I know someone thought of this and made some conscious (but weird) decission. (Maybe that's because I am german and used to spelling 24 as "four-and-twenty" :D)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "what the..." moment the first time I saw `new int[5][];` instead of `new int[][5];`.

EL's (very nice) blog post is dancing around one thing: there's a perfect way to do it *for people with a ComSci degree*, but no good way to do it for others. If you just follow the grammar, you declare right-to-left, `new` right-to-left and index left-to-right:

```
// 1D array of 2D arrays, no special rules needed:
int[,][] N; N=new[,][5]; N[0]=new int[4,4];
```

But C#'s target audience isn't people with 4-year CS degrees (who have all seen Reverse Polish and love right-to-left.) The trick, IMHO, in understanding C# jagged arrays is that they decided to make special rules for them, when they didn't technically need to.